# Return unique row only - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a customer table and order tables. In customer table we have 'Family link' column which is a given ID to each customer. e.g. familyLink: A121, if this customer has a family member in the table they will have this ID too : A121. Basically I need to return all customers with no family members and have made an order_number 2 or 3

`Customer` table:

```
CustmID(PK), Name(varchar), familyLink(varchar).
```

`Order` table:

```
OrderID(PK), order_number (varchar), CustmID(FK)
```

The query I've return which didn't seem to return customers with no family member..

```
Select Distinct 
    c.familyLink,
    c.name,
    o.order_number
From 
    Customer c
Left join 
    Order o on c.CustmID = o.CustmID
where 
    (o.order_number = 2 or order_number=3)
```

**Examples:**

Customer table

```
Custm ID   Name   FamilyLink
C1         Liam     A11
C2         Lucy     A12
C3         David    A11
C4         Suzy     A13
```

Orders table

```
OrderID    Order_Number     CustmID
O1           2               C1
O2           3               C2
O3           2               C4
```

**Results`**
This query should return Lucy and Suzy because they don't have any family members in the customer table..

Any idea why this is returning customers who share familyLink?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Order` is a reserved T-SQL keyword  - you should **avoid** using it for your own tables, if ever possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea why this is returning customers who share familyLink ?

Because nothing in your query is limiting it to that. You're asking for all rows where you the `o.order_number = 2` or `order_number = 3`; there's nothing about "not returning customers that don't have a family link".

You also have a syntax error in your SQL, specifically `Left join Order`. `ORDER` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server, and in most (if not every) SQL language. It is **strongly** advised that you do not give objects names that are a Reserved keyword or a [Future Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#future-keywords). If you *do* have an object that has an Reserved Keyword for a name, you **must** quote it: `[Order]`.

As for what you are after, this is a total guess, but perhaps:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT C.familyLink,
           C.name,
           O.order_number,
           COUNT(C.CustmID) OVER (PARTITION BY O.order_number) AS Customers
    FROM Customer C
         INNER JOIN [Order] O ON C.CustmID = O.CustmID --This is an INNER JOIN, as the WHERE must be met, so there can never not be a row
    WHERE O.order_number IN (2,3))
SELECT C.familyLink,
       C.name,
       C.order_number
FROM CTE
WHERE Customers = 1;
```

If this doesn't work, you'll need to provide sample data and expected results. I put this an answer, however, as my opening statements were also far too long for a comment.

Comment: Could you pls explain this line : COUNT(C.CustmID) OVER (PARTITION BY O.order_number) AS Customers

Comment: I'll test it now.. I understand the rest but not that line.

Comment: It counts the number of non-`NULL` values with the same value for `O.order_number`, @Sam .

Comment: It's not working.. It's returning customers with family link.. did you mean (Count(c.familylink))? I've tried it too but not returning unique ones

Comment: You ***need*** to supply that sample data and expected results I asks for then, @Sam ; we're working blind here and what you're saying doesn't really make sense. This was a best guess with warnings about your SQL.

Comment: Apology for not being clear. I've provided an example